# Cannot script SQL Server database objects on AWS RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using SQL Server on AWS RDS and the script function (right click an index and script create script, for example) got the following error.

> script invalid Urn filter on server level: filter must be empty, or server attribute must be equal with the true server name.

How to workaround the issue?

Comment: Is it really related to RDS? Works for me on RDS instance.

Comment: yes, it used to work. and today it got this error message.

Comment: Works for me (US-EAST-1, SQL Server 14.0.3035, SSMS 14.0.17254.0)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://debabratahowlee.blogspot.com/2016/09/sql-server-invalid-urn-filter-on-server.html) can help.

Comment: Probably not worthy of an answer, especially considering it's 2 years later, but I restarted SSMS and reconnected to the server and it worked for me then.